# Generic .htaccess folder redirect with variable root paths

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I want to do a simple redirect so that a request for app/scans/large/as89q6dfa.jpg results in app/scans/medium/as89q6dfa.jpg, etc. The trouble is that this app will be used on a few domains with different base paths. The code I've tried keeps rewriting to the absolute base path of the site and the app is actually a variable number of folders deep on the site. Is there a generalized way to do a redirect like this, without hard-coding the base path?

Here's my file and folder scructure:

```
app/.htaccess
app/scans/large
app/scans/medium
```

So the .htaccess rules should work for:

```
includes/app/scans/large
inc/app/scans/large
script/engine/app/scans/large
```

Here's my first attempt:

```
RedirectMatch 301 scans/large/(.*) scans/medium//$1
```

Here's my second attempt:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^scans/large/(.*) scans/medium/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use the "^" caracter it means that the regex will search for the string "scans/large" in the **BEGINNING** of the URL.

So as the base is "/", it won't work on "includes/app/scans/large/omg" because "scans" it's not in the beginning of the string.

Try this solution:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule (.*)scans/large/(.*) $1scans/medium/$2 [R=301,L]
```

It worked perfectly with the URL:

```
http://www.example.com/includes/app/scans/large/omg
```

That redirects to:

```
http://www.example.com/includes/app/scans/medium/omg
```

You can do more tests on it here: [link](http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/)

Comment: I was having other problems with my WAMP server too (needed to setup vhosts), now fixed. The carrot was key and great link. It could be simplified further: RewriteRule scans/large/(.*) scans/medium/$1 [R=301,L]

Answer (score 0):

You can actually get `RewriteBase` be determined dynamically.

```
RewriteEngine On

# determine BASE dynamically
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(.*?/)(.*)::\2$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [E=BASE:%1]

RewriteRule ^scans/large/(.*)$ %{ENV:BASE}scans/medium/$1 [R=301,L,NC]
```